Trying to build core-image-minimal on yocto. compilation failed due to:ERROR: qemu-native-4.1.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
On poky trying to compile core-image-minimal for the first time.

`Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.44.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "x86_64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "qemux86-64"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.0.4"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "m64 core2"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "<unknown>:<unknown>"`

Error raised during compilations and the compilation fails:
`ERROR: qemu-native-4.1.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: qemu-native-4.1.0-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/4.1.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.4889' failed with exit code 1:
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/4.1.0-r0/qemu-4.1.0/slirp'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/4.1.0-r0/qemu-4.1.0/slirp'
  CXX     disas/nanomips.o
g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/home/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/4.1.0-r0/qemu-4.1.0/rules.mak:94: disas/nanomips.o] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file 'disas/nanomips.o'
WARNING: /home/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/4.1.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.4889:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/4.1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.4889`

**couldn't find a proper solution to the issue. is there a mismatch of version I need to be aware of?
Thanks in advance.**
I tried to install cmake, checked for g++ version. didnt help.
